# firebase child exists or not in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My question is similar to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420650/proper-use-of-haschild-and-foreach-from-a-reference-in-firebase)

1. I have a Firebase path called for a users table, say appname/users
2. I want to see if a user exists.
3. I obtain a reference: Firebase users =
   ref.child('users');

I am wondering if there is an equivalent Java code similar to the javascript answer provided. I ask this because in the latest version of Firebase-client that I am using I am unable to find the method once(), which has been called to see if a child exists or not.

EDIT 1:

I am using the Eclipse IDE for development and I have download the firebase jar from the location specified in the web page. I am unable to use a couple of methods as I do not see any of them being specified.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(url);
Firebase usersRef = ref.child("users");
```

When I try to use the method once()/ hasChild() the IDE does not show any of these methods being available. I am not sure if it is only at my end or if I need to download and use another jar? 
[image: here]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share some code? Once certainly exists in Java and JavaScript SDKs.

Comment: @Kato I have updated the question with some more information

Comment: This question has been asked and you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37401490/7128506)

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is [addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent%28com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener%29). It is the Java equivalent to the 'once' function in javascript. In addition, the 'hasChild' method is available on the [DataSnapshot](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html) class, which will be provided in the callback to your listener. In general, you can find all of the Java API documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/index.html

Comment: I tried the childEventListener(), I was able to lop through the entries easily .

Comment: @Greg Soltis. It is async call with no callback if the child does not exist. That leads to ambiguity, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343593/check-key-existence-in-firebase-for-android-synchronous)