# Detect if a child exists

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to check if a child exists in a location like this:

```
public static boolean checkIfNotebookExists(String notebookName) {
    if (notebooksRef.child(notebookName) == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Whenever I call this function, I always get `true` even though the parameter that I include doesn't exist yet on the database.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378400/firebase-child-exists-or-not-in-android

Comment: An example with code: https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323949#gistcomment-998628