# Check Key Existence in Firebase for Android (synchronous)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying find out if a Firebase key exists using Firebase Android Api. Here is the code snippet:

```
  Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://[MYFB].firebaseio.com/");
  ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
          dataSnapshot.getKey();
        }
      }
      //...
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError err) {
      }
    });
```

The problem with this approach is that I can't get a '*DataSnapshot*' without resorting to asynchronous callback '*ChildEventListener()*'. Since the call is asynchronous, my code does not know if the key doesn't exist or the *onChildAdded()* has not been consumed yet.
When searching for a solution I found the method '*.once()*' in JS Api that would solve the problem, but there is no 'synchronous' equivalent in the Android Api.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Java has built-in mechanisms to deal with this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705 . But I recommend taking the red pill and accepting the asynchronous nature of this process.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's what I'm doing now, but it gets really messy considering that I'm storing values from another async universe - [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro). Thanks!

Comment: The solution is typically to not *store* the value, but to update the UI whenever the value changes. Note btw that `once()` in JavaScript is also asynchronous. Firebase doesn't offer synchronous data access, since that is counter to the logic of monitoring a location for all data changes.