# Google firebase check if child exists

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I need to check if a given element of my database on firebase has a child with a given name. I hoped it could be done by using something along the lines of:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

if (rootRef.childExists("name")) {
    //run some code
}
```

I searched but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36826793/3145960

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding if data exists in Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826429/understanding-if-data-exists-in-firebase)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Edit 2; worth putting on top:** I think it is worth mentioning that this is actually downloading all data at this snapshot just to check whether any data exists. You should be mindful here. If the reference is huge (e.g. *actually* the root reference and not a specific child/property) then you should either find a deeper node you can use to check for existence or design your data structure differently so an efficient check is possible.

A database reference is effectively the URL for that data. You want to actually *get* data to see whether a child exists. This is why the method you seem to be looking for is on [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot).

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild("name")) {
      // run some code
    }
  }
});
```

Now, this design pattern feels a bit strange. You're reading the whole database just to see whether "name" exists. You can make this a bit more efficient by listening to `rootRef.child("name")` and then just checking whether `snapshot.exists()`.

If you're trying to do *validation* here, and not control flow, you should consider putting this code in your `rules.json`.

**edit**: I originally used the wrong function name (childExists instead of hasChild)

Comment: Just to clarify: Is it possible to access data on firebase without a listener?

Comment: I assume you're asking because you don't want the callback to run over and over. The "single" in the above code means that this only fires once.

Comment: Yes. Thanks very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752247/how-to-check-existed-data-in-firebase

Comment: if DatabaseReference not exist onDataChange not called, because no any data, called method onCancelled()

Comment: This will take all data under the database ref

Comment: @ThomasBouldin I am using the same code i.e.    if(dataSnapshot).hasChild("name") but it always returns false when it runs for the first time. If I run it again then it runs the expected value i.e. true. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: @AyushMalviya this is because you have offline mode turned on. It checks first against your cache and then sets a listener against the node. You won’t get a second notification if the server matches the local cache so you have two options: make your app responsive to changes (what you generally intend when you have a listener) or bypass the cache by using a once query.

Answer (score 10):

**Don't do like this**

**NEVER**

It will take all your data and bring to device

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild("name")) {
      // run some code
    }
  }
});
```

Check it by this way.
It will return the value of the child if exists, otherwise -> null

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("childName")
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.getValue() == null) {
      // The child doesn't exist
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't I use `snapshot.exists()`?

Comment: IT doesen't make sense to to write "rootRef.child("childName")" when you are adding listener to the root node. Have you tested your code before posting this?

Answer (score 6):

A complete solution. No need to download all the data. Just check if the child exist like this:

```
// Assuming the names are in the name node. Remove "name/" if not
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("name/" + name);
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.exists()) {
             // Exist! Do whatever.

         } else {
             // Don't exist! Do something.

         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed, how to handle?

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.childexists`  in combination with `.equalTo("Your specific name")`

Answer (score 0):

```
UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();   
Users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasChild("childName")) {

                                        // it exists!
                                    }else{
                                       // does not exist
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use snapshot.exists() to check if the referenced database entry contains a child , irrespective of the  value of the child.