# Check if child exists in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Android Java Firebase:

```
 DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference users = root.child("Users");
users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.childExists("name")) {
                    // run some code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

This is my code, but `childexists` is not a valid working method. What is a way to check? If there is something similar can I just fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397205/google-firebase-check-if-child-exists

Answer (score 3):

Either use [`hasChild()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#hasChild(java.lang.String)):

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild("name")) {
        // run some code
    }
}
```

Or [`child().exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()):

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.child("name").exists()) {
        // run some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not aware how Firebase works in this regard, does the OnValueListener actually grab all the data from the database? Just wondering if this would be the right solution for a database with thousands of user entries etc.