# Is there anyway to find a Child by the key value with a Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the exported JSON from my Firebase Database:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "115737970494961514401" : {
      "createDate" : {
        "date" : 5,
        "day" : 1,
        "hours" : 15,
        "minutes" : 19,
        "month" : 11,
        "seconds" : 32,
        "time" : 1480972772566,
        "timezoneOffset" : 360,
        "year" : 116
      },
      "email" : "wang.zhexi@gmail.com",
      "fName" : "Michael",
      "lName" : "Wang"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can look for the specific key of `115737970494961514401`? I am developing in Android Studio.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve data from that user id(115737970494961514401) ?

Comment: No, it's just an example. I would want to see if 115737970494961514401 existed, and if not, add that user.

Comment: There are likely to be some good results in this list: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+check+if+node+exists Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like  how it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37401490/7128506)

Yours would look something like this:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users);
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild("some unique id")) {
      // run some code to add user
    }
  }
});
```