# How do I check if a child exists in Firebase xamarin?

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android, fire-sharp

I'm using firebase for c# xamarin and I want to do for each user it will check if he has counter, and if not it will generate for him. I tried it like this:

```
try
{
    FirebaseResponse resp = await client.GetAsync(uid+"/counter/node");
    result = resp.ResultAs<Counter_Class>();
}
catch
{
    var counter = new Counter_Class
    {
        cnt = "0"
    };
    SetResponse response = await client.SetAsync(uid + "counter/node", counter);
    Counter_Class result = response.ResultAs<Counter_Class>(); //The response will contain the data written
}
```

When the child exists the try/catch is fine but when it doesn't and the catch need to generate a child it shut down.
can I check if the child exists like `if(childexists)?
I'm using c# not java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google firebase check if child exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397205/google-firebase-check-if-child-exists)

Comment: No, I need it in c#

Comment: It seems like the [FireSharp library](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/blob/c361b28baa40d03d0518387eb28e21b595ebb269/FireSharp.Core/Response/FirebaseResponse.cs) that you use doesn't implement `HasChild` that the linked answer depends on.

Comment: I dont need the code to be with the firesharp library i need just a code that matches c# xamarin